# Does re-running a map in react re-call the expensive function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following loop (simplified):

```js
const ExpensiveItems = useMemo(() => {
  return items.map((item, idx) => {
    const style = {
      marginTop: V_GAP,
      ...(idx === items.length - 1 && { marginBottom: V_GAP }),
    };
    return <ExpensiveComponent style={style} item={item} />;
  });
}, [items]);

return loading ? <div>Loading...</div> 
    : <div>{ExpensiveItems}</div>
```

Whenever, `items` changes will the `ExpensiveComponent` function be called *N* times where *N* is the length of `items`. Or will React diff the props first and only call the `ExpensiveComponent` function again if and only if the props have changed?

This is possibly premature optimization, but if the `ExpensiveComponent` function will be called *N* times each time the `items` array changes, I'd like to avoid calling it `N` times if possible, since usually at most 1 item in the `items` array will change at a given time.

So the question is: If re-calling `items.map` will call the `ExpensiveComponent` function `N` times, is there a way to optimize this `map` function further so that if a single item in the `items` array changes, I don't do that?

Comment: `map` does not call the `ExpensiveComponent`  (function component?) directly. It only returns JSX elements, which React will then render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever, items changes will the ExpensiveComponent function be called N times where N is the length of items

Yes, it will, unless ExpensiveComponent is a PureComponent (which only re-render if the props change).

But this is a strange problem to have - the *rendering* of components shouldn't be expensive at all, unless you have many of them and they have an unreasonable number of children each. Otherwise, if the rendering is expensive, you should refactor them so that they only perform whatever the expensive calculation is when they really need to, and not on every re-render.

Just for example, don't do

```
const ExpensiveComponent = ({ style, item }) => {
  const result = someBigCalculation(item);
  // ...
  return <div>{result}</div>
}
```

Instead do

```
const ExpensiveComponent = ({ style, item }) => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState();
  useEffect(() => setResult(someBigCalculation(item)), [item]);
```

In decently structured code, running the top level of a component to re-render shouldn't be expensive in the vast majority of situations, though there are a few exceptions.

Comment: Don't use `useEffect` to initialise stuff, that'll cause an unnecessary rerender. Use `const result = useMemo(() => someBigCalculation(item)), [item]);`.

Comment: That's the right approach when it's certain that the prop will never change, but I didn't want to assume that